# How to reset default margin in React styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am new to react styled-components. I want to reset the default margin for all elements. I did it using `createGlobalStyle` as

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import normalize from 'normalize.css';

export default createGlobalStyle`
    ${normalize}

    *, *::after, *::before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
`
```

and updated my `index.js` to be

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import GlobalStyles from './[path]/GlobalStyles';

ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <GlobalStyles />
    <App />
  </>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

However, when I use an `h1` element, I noticed that it has default margins, and it's gone only when I specify the `h1` element with zero margin in my global styles.

Why? and how can I reset the margin for ALL elements using `*` selector?

Comment: Inspect the `h1` element in the DOM, in the computed style tab, look to see what is setting any margin rules.

Comment: @DrewReese The `margin-block-end`, `margin-block-start`, `margin-top`, and `margin-bottom` the value is `13.4px`, and when expanding these it indicates that the margin is caused by `h1`. All other margins and paddings are 0. Does this provide any useful information?